# Created my own vector class. Able to overload stream operator, but can not print by value c++

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to programming and our teacher had us create our own vector class. Everything works as needed, however once I hit the bottom and try to use the printV function, the size of the function is increased to a really large number instead of retaining the size of the vector. I will include all of the code below.

```
using namespace std;
class MyVector
{
private:
    int vectorSize;
    int maxCapacity;
    int *myArray;
public:
    //default constructor
    //purpose: Initializes all variables
    MyVector(void);
    //Parameterized Constructor
    //Purpose: creates a vector of capacity n
    //parameters: int
    MyVector(int);
    //destructor
    //Purpose: deletes and dynamically allocated storage
    ~MyVector(void);
    // Overloaded assignment operator
    // Purpose: to do assignment from one vector to another
    // Parameters: a MyVector object
    // Returns: A MyVector object
    MyVector operator + (MyVector&);
    // Copy constructor
    // Purpose: Copy the data into this vector
    // Parameters: a MyVector object
    // Returns: none
    MyVector(const MyVector&);
    //size function
    //purpose: gets the size of the vector
    //returns: size
    int size() const;
    //capacity function
    //purpose: gets the capacity of the vector
    //returns: capacity
    int capacity() const;
    //clear function
    //purpose: deletes all elements from the vector and resets its size to zero and capacity 2
    //returns: nothing
    void clear();
    //push_back function
    //purpose: adds an integer value at the end of the vector
    //returns: nothing
    void push_back(int n);
    //at function
    //purpose: returns the value of the element at position i in the vector
    int at(int) const;
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const MyVector&);
```

Here is the cpp file

```
#include "MyVector.h"


MyVector::MyVector(void)
{
    maxCapacity = 2;
    myArray = new int[maxCapacity];
    vectorSize = 0;
}

MyVector::MyVector(int i)
{
    maxCapacity = i;
    myArray = new int[maxCapacity];
    vectorSize = 0;
}

MyVector::~MyVector(void)
{
    if (myArray != NULL);
    {
        delete [] myArray;
        myArray = NULL;
    }
}
MyVector MyVector::operator+(MyVector& rho)
{
    if (this == &rho)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    delete [ ] this->myArray;
    vectorSize = rho.vectorSize;
    this->myArray = new int[maxCapacity];
    for(int i = 0; i < maxCapacity; i++)
    {
        this->myArray[i] = rho.myArray[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
MyVector::MyVector(const MyVector& b)
{
    maxCapacity = b.maxCapacity;
    myArray = new int[maxCapacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < maxCapacity; i++)
    {
        this->myArray[i] = b.myArray[i];
    }
}
int MyVector::size() const
{
    return vectorSize;
}
int MyVector::capacity() const
{
    return maxCapacity;
}
void MyVector::clear()
{
    delete [] myArray;
    maxCapacity = 2;
    myArray = new int[maxCapacity];
    vectorSize = 0;
}
void MyVector::push_back(int add_Element)
{
    if(vectorSize+1>maxCapacity)
    {
        maxCapacity = maxCapacity*2;
        int* tmp = new int[maxCapacity];
        for(int i=0; i <vectorSize; i++)
        {
            tmp[i] = myArray[i];
        }
        delete[] myArray;
        myArray = tmp;
    }

    myArray[vectorSize] = add_Element;
    vectorSize++;
}
int MyVector::at(int i) const
{
    if(i >= vectorSize)
    {
        throw i;
    }
    else
    {
        return myArray[i];
    }
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& theStream, const MyVector& aVector)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < aVector.size(); i++)
    {
        theStream << aVector.at(i);
    }
    return theStream;
}
```

And of course the Driver. I am unable to change the driver

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyVector.h"     
using namespace std;

// the printV function
// used to test the copy constructor
// parameter: a MyVector object
void printV(MyVector);

int main( )
{
    cout << "\nCreating a vector Sam of size 4.";
    MyVector sam( 4 );

    cout << "\nPush 12 values into the vector.";
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        sam.push_back(i);

    cout << "\nHere is sam: ";
    cout << sam;
    cout << "\n---------------\n";

        cout << "\nCreating a vector Joe of size 4.";
    MyVector joe( 4 );
    cout << "\nPush 6 values into the vector.";
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        joe.push_back(i * 3);

    cout << "\nHere is joe: ";
    cout << joe;
    cout << "\n---------------\n";

    cout << "\nTest the overloaded assignment operator \"joe = sam\": ";
    joe = sam;

    cout << "\nHere is sam: ";
    cout << sam;
    cout << "\n---------------\n";

    cout << "\nHere is joe: ";
    cout << joe;
    cout << "\n---------------\n";

    // pass a copy of sam by value
    printV(sam);//my problem is here! It changes the array size to a very large number


    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void printV(MyVector v)
{
    cout << "\n--------------------\n";
    cout << "Printing a copy of a vector\n";
    cout << v;
}
```

Comment: Yawn... Rule of Three... mumble mumble...

Comment: sorry, if you don't mind me asking. What is the Rule of Three?

Comment: You're better off searching for such things yourself. "Rule of three C++" on google yields http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29

Comment: Thanks, so i'm guessing the problem is with a pointer in one of the Rule of three.

Comment: More accurately, the problem is with a pointer as a result of not following the rule.

Comment: Thanks figured it out, I was missing a & in my cpp file of the overloaded assignment operator :D problem is solved

Comment: You don't have to check if a pointer is NULL in order to delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing

```
vectorSize = b.vectorSize;
```

line in your copy constructor `MyVector::MyVector(const MyVector& b)`

Comment: I think you're right, although using the *ctor-initializer-list* would be better.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was something I was missing.

However I am getting a new error now that the debug assertion failed! Expressing: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse

Comment: Your destructor also has an extra semicolon that will make it do something other than it looks like it does. It doesn't matter in this case because it's safe to delete a null pointer, but it's still there.

Comment: That assertion means you have a buffer overrun or other bad pointer use somewhere.

Comment: Oops. Fixed that. They array is now fixed so it output is correct. Thanks Joel, I'll look and see if I can see it anywhere.